# Where do I set a HTML file/page in the root of my React Project to land on example.com/login.html?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, single-page-application

I am trying to authenticate a user using a third-party auth server. Their redirect_uri states after the user logs in, they will be redirect to example.com/login.html.

Within the login.html file, there will be some html/ script to handle the authentication. Since this project is in React, where can I put this file belong in the project?

```
my-app
├── build
├── node_modules
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   └── manifest.json
├── src
│   ├── App.css
│   ├── App.js
│   ├── App.test.js
│   ├── index.css
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── logo.svg
│   └── serviceWorker.js
├── .gitignore
├── login.html <--------------- ??????
├── package.json
└── README.md
```

The end result should be if I visit example.com/login.html, I would see the html/script in the inspector and only the html/script **(no JSX, no div id="root")**. Just whatever there is in that simple plain HTML/ script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't have to do with React, just how your server is serving static files (like the `login.html` file).

If you're using Create-React-App in development mode, try putting it in the `public` directory. Note this server is only meant to be used for local development, NOT as a standalone/production server

In production mode things will be different, and you'll need to configure middleware for your static files. If you're using Express it might look like this:

`app.use(express.static('public'))`

Alternatively you could set up a separate Express route just for that one login page, like:

`app.get('/login', (req, res) => res.sendFile('public/login.html'))`

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down in Dev vs Prod. It works placing this in the ```public``` directory.